# lock statement saturation

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass instanceOfClass = new TestClass();
        while (true)
        {
            Thread threadTest = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AddNewToClass));
            threadTest.Start(instanceOfClass);
        }
    }
    static void AddNewToClass(object parameter)
    {
        var instance = (TestClass)parameter;
        while (true)
        {
            if (instance.Contains(1))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                instance.AddNew(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dictionary;
    public TestClass()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }
    public void AddNew(int test)
    {
        lock (dictionary)
        {
            dictionary.Add(test, "Test string");
        }
    }
    public bool Contains(int test)
    {
        lock (dictionary)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(test))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is to have several different threads that add/remove objects from a Dictionary. I tried running this and I get this exception:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Which seems extremely weird. As far as I know the lock statement should block the dictionary in question and TestClass.Contains(1) should **always** return true, and it is throwing an exception as it returned true more than once (therefore the exception).

Anyone knows why this might happen? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Contains()` method is atomic. So is your `Add()` method. `AddNewToClass()`, however, is not. One thread may get a result from `Contains()`...but there's no guarantee regarding when it might or might not be suspended (or resumed).

That's your race condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your lock only protects the blocks that it surrounds - it is this that needs protection

```
static void AddNewToClass(object parameter)
    {
        var instance = (TestClass)parameter;
        while (true)
        {
            if (instance.Contains(1))
            {
                continue;
            }  
            else
            {
                instance.AddNew(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Between the `if (instance.Contains(1))` and the `instance.AddNew(1);` you can get preempted.

If you went with something like `instance.AddItemIfMissing(1);`

```
public void AddItemIfMissing(int test)
{
    lock (dictionary)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(test))
        {
           dictionary.Add(test, "Test string");
        }
    }
}
```

This would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have a racing condition. After you lock on, you need to check again if the dictionary already contains an item by the same key, since another thread might have added it before you acquired the lock. But why reinvent the wheel? There are numerous helper classes, like ConcurrentBag, in the Parallel Extensions library. Or use a well thought through Singleton Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void AddNewToClass(object parameter)
{
    var instance = (TestClass)parameter;
    while (true)
    {
        if (instance.Contains(1))
        {
            continue;
        }    // **thread switch maybe happens here will cause your problem** 
        else
        {
            instance.AddNew(1);
        }
    }
}
```

So following is better

```
    lock(instance)
    {
        if (instance.Contains(1))
        {
            continue;
        }    // **thread switch maybe happens here will cause your problem** 
        else
        {
            instance.AddNew(1);
        }
    }
```